# Does CVE-2017-8759 impact the web service?

Tags: web-service, zero-day

I saw lots of information on the impact to end user PC, but didn't see anywhere explain the impact to the cloud service. If the issue is from the SOAP WSDL parsing, seems like the web service can also be impacted right?

Looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 1):

If by „web-service“ and „the cloud service“ you mean a cloud hosted office instance (which is not what a web service is), the answer is going to be maybe, depending on wether that vulnerable parser is deployed in the product.

I couldn’t find a definitive answer to that in 5 minutes of googling; the vulnerable parser [seems to be from](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-8759)

> Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0, 3.5, 3.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2 and 4.7

Answer (score 0):

WSDL is used to subscribe web service not to exchange information between client and server.
It means that the impact to the web server is less likely.